# brew install postgresql fails on Mac OS X Lion (10.7.4) with XCode 4.3.3

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I'm running into an error while installing postgresql 9.1.4 with homebrew. I've tried everything I can think of to work around the problem including....

- running `brew install --use-gcc postgresql`
- running `brew install --use-clang postgresql`
- running `brew install --use-llvm postgresql`
- running `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 brew install postgresql`
- running `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 && brew install postgresql`
- running `brew install postgresql --32-bit`
- running `brew install postgresql --without-ossp-uuid`
- running `brew install postgresql --no-python`
- running `PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python brew install postgresql`

I've noticed that postgreqsl 9.0.4 is already installed on the system, but many of the commands that I'd expect to be there are missing, such as `initdb` and `pg_ctl`, so I don't want to use that version.

I suspect that the issue I'm encountering is caused by libraries from the system version of postgresql are being linked against, but I'm not sure how to test this.

Any thoughts? I posted the verbose output of running `brew install postgresql` in a gist. https://gist.github.com/2998598

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is now a known issue and is fixed by **[applying a Homebrew patch](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13044)**.